# react-native-router-flux addListener doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using

react-native": "0.62.2",
react-native-router-flux: "4.2.0-beta.1",

addListener doesn't work, and console.log never invoke

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.addListener(ActionConst.RESET, () => {
            console.log('RESET');
        });
        this.props.navigation.addListener(ActionConst.FOCUS, () => {
            console.log('FOCUS');
        });
        this.props.navigation.addListener(ActionConst.PUSH, () => {
            console.log('PUSH');
        });
        this.props.navigation.addListener(ActionConst.POP_TO, () => {
            console.log('POP_TO');
        });
}
```

is there a way or documentation that I can look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have

- willFocus - the screen will focus
- didFocus - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
- willBlur - the screen will be unfocused
- didBlur - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

To add listener

```js
componentDidMount(){
    const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didBlur',() => {
         console.log('didBlur');
       }
    );
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    // Remove the listener when you are done
    didBlurSubscription.remove();
}
```

[DOC](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-prop/#addlistener---subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)
(v4.2.x is [based on](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#v42x-is-based-on-react-navigation-v4x) React Navigation v4.x)